# Leaflet ImageOverlay of GeoTIFF

Tags: leaflet, geotiff-tiff

Below example uses Leaflet L.ImageOverlay to show GeoTIFF. The issue is the image data doesn't match the GeoTIFF bounds shown by the markers and the image seems to be shifted northwest.

If you click just above and to the left of the top marker you get some data. Similarly, no data above the lower marker.

Is this an issue with projection since the GeoTIFF file is in EPSG:4326? I tried other GeoTIFF files and it is apparent on the shorelines not aligning with map tiles and always shifting northwest.

I don't see this issue when using GeoTIFF libraries that use imageoverlay like leaflet-geotiff. However, they make the canvas the same size as the map and place the image at the geotiff northwest bound and they match very well. The only issue with that is they keep redrawing the image at every zoom or move which make them very slow with larger files.

[Here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/mtcl/pen/KKeRLBb?editors=1010) based on [this example](https://geoexamples.com/d3-raster-tools-docs/plot/leaflet.html)

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Q/A on GIS SE site are not intended only to solve problem of particular user, but be helpful resource for anybody with similar questions/problems. That's the reason question has to be complete in itself and include all relevant code as text, since outside links tend to get lost in time and also that there is no need to visit other sites to get complete picture of what the problem is. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: It doesn't look like an issue with the projection but with the simplification of the raster data using ```Math.round``` - the issue is on all sides btw.

Comment: Yes, I believe the issue is with getting pixel values on the click. I fixed it in the codepen for anyone interested in line 95 & 96. I still have alignment issue with canvas values and rgb colors not matching but that is for another question.

Answer (score 2):

@Bernd Loigge is right, shift is consequence of rounding. I tried the following simple trick to remedy that, and it works:

```
var xTiff = (e.latlng.lng - geoTransform[0])/geoTransform[1] - 0.5;
var yTiff = (e.latlng.lat - geoTransform[3])/geoTransform[5] - 0.5;
```